# How to disable close button icon on popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have a link on my website which is opening a popup. I want to disable the close "X" button on the browser.

Note: the onBeforeUnload event is not working.

I need another way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Find id or class of close "X" button and hide button using that class or id before popup like $(".class").hide()

Answer (score 0):

```
if You are using JqueryUI popUp function its sligthhly difficult to do 
otherwise just give the button  X  a class then do something like this.

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- two method of doing this -->
<!-- 1 method use display none -->
<button class="close"style="display:none">X</button>
<script>

//or use script 
//using jQuery selection method 

     $(".close").hide();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```